# any annotation equivalent to @Override for overriding (hiding) static methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, static, overriding

as it is explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html), in java static methods are not overridden but hidden by child implementations

that means that you can't use @Override annotations with them

the following code

```
@Override
public static void test(String value1, String value2) {
```

gives this compiler error.

```
The method test(String, String) of type Child must override or implement a supertype method Child.java
```

is there some equivalent annotation that I could use to make sure my class is "hiding" an existing static method from parent class?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish by hiding the superclass static method?

Comment: I'm playing with play framework, which uses static methods for controllers actions (there's a whole argument about using static methods for that purpose) I defined a base controller and I want to override the method ona child controller...

Comment: Really don't do that. I guess it should be linted and the (in)appropriate annotation would be `@SuppressWarnings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any annotations that you can add. But simply creating the method with the exact same name and inputs (the same method signature) should hide it. The only way to know for sure is to know the details of the superclass method for sure, and then perhaps test your method... Thats all I can think of. The only other annotations I can think of would be to suppress warnings which would be the opposite of what you want I imagine. Whenever I hide a method like this I generally get a warning from my IDE telling me that I am hiding another method.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy one: No.

Check out [the list of standard compiler annotations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)